# How are null telephone numbers getting into my JavaScript .length restricted form field?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, angularjs, forms

I feel I have a problem which is probably browser specific? If anyone has some insight any help would be appreciated.

I have some javascript which restricts form input values based on length. The form is contest and the contest website was launched this morning. We've so far received just over 100 entries. Everything has gone as expected except for the telephone number column which is occasionally letting in `Null` values (5 out of 100 have been `Null`).

The problem is I am unable to reproduce the error. Here is the javascript which restricts form input values for the telephone field:

First, I restrict entry of values to numbers only like this:

```
// js
function numbersOnlyInput (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if ( charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

<!-- html -->
<input class="contact-input" name="telephone" type="text" id="telephone" placeholder="Téléphone" onkeypress="return numbersOnlyInput(event)"  ng-click="userInfoFormBlock_AllQuestions()" />
```

Second, I have an on submit function which restricts this input's value to a length of 10:

```
// extracted from on submit js function
            var prenom = $('#prenom').val(),
                nom = $('#nom').val(),
                email = $('#email').val(),
                adresse = $('#adresse').val(),
                postal = $('#postal').val(),
                ville = $('#ville').val(),
                ticket = $('#ticket option:selected').text(),
                telephone = $('#telephone').val(),
                eula = $('#eula').prop('checked');

            if ( $('#eula').prop('checked') == false 
                    || email.indexOf('@') == -1 
                    || email.indexOf('.') == -1 
                    || postal.length != 5 
                    || telephone.length != 10 
                    || prenom == ""
                    || prenom == " "
                    || prenom == null
                    || nom == ""
                    || nom == " "
                    || nom == null
                    || adresse == ""
                    || adresse == " "
                    || adresse == null
                    || ville == ""
                    || ville == " "
                    || ville == null) {


                // reset contest rules checkbox
                $('#eula').prop('checked', false);
                // empty popup
                $('#form-popup-text').html('');
                var showFormPopup = false;

                if ( prenom == "" || prenom == " " || prenom == null ) {
                    $('#prenom').css('background', "#B20000");
                    $('#form-popup-text').append("<p>Prénom* - Le champ prénom est vide</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#prenom').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( nom == "" || nom == " " || nom == null ) {
                    $('#nom').css('background', "#B20000");
                    $('#form-popup-text').append("<p>Nom* - Le champ nom est vide</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#nom').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( email.indexOf('@') == -1 || email.indexOf('.') == -1 ) {
                    $('#email').css('background', "#B20000");
                    $('#form-popup-text').append("<p>Email* - L'adresse mail ne semble pas valide</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#email').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( adresse == "" || adresse == " " || adresse == null ) {
                    $('#adresse').css('background', "#B20000");
                    $('#form-popup-text').append("<p>Adresse* - Le champ adresse est vide</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#adresse').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( ville == "" || ville == " " || ville == null ) {
                    $('#ville').css('background', "#B20000");
                    $('#form-popup-text').append("<p>Ville* - Le champ ville est vide</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#ville').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( postal.length != 5 ) {
                    $('#postal').css('background', "#B20000");
                    $("#form-popup-text").append("<p>Code postal* - Le code postal doit contenir 5 chiffres</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#postal').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( telephone.length != 10 ) {
                    $("#telephone").css('background', "#B20000");
                    $("#form-popup-text").append("<p>Téléphone* - Le numéro de téléphone doit contenir 10 chiffres</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }else{
                    $('#telephone').css('background', "#3a3a3a");
                }
                if ( $('#eula').prop('checked') == false ) {
                    $("#form-popup-text").append("<p>Vous devez accepter les modalités du concours</p>");
                    showFormPopup = true;
                }

                if(showFormPopup) {
                    $('#form-popup-wrapper').show();
                    $scope.showVideoOverlay = true;
                }
                userInfoFormComplete();
            } else {

                // post to database
                $http.post("data/save.php", {
                    'name': $scope.name,
                    'family_name': $scope.familyName,
                    'email': $scope.email,
                    'address': $scope.address,
                    'city': $scope.ville,
                    'postal_code': $scope.postalCode,
                    'telephone': $scope.telephone,
                    'event_ticket': $scope.ticket,
                    'mailing_list': $scope.mailingList,
                    'score': $scope.correctAnswers,
                    'perfect_score': perfectScore,
                    'answer1': $scope.answer[0],
                    'answer2': $scope.answer[1],
                    'answer3': $scope.answer[2],
                    'answer4': $scope.answer[3],
                    'answer5': $scope.answer[4],
                    'answer6': $scope.answer[5],
                    'answer7': $scope.answer[6],
                    'answer8': $scope.answer[7],
                    'answer9': $scope.answer[8]
                }).success( function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    //console.log("Database updated successfully");
                }).error( function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(headers);
                    console.log(config);
                });

                $scope.formSubmitted = true;
```

So! Anyone know how the 5 null values (of 100 records) for the telephone field have gotten posted to the db? Everything else seems to be working fine and since I can't reproduce the error in Chrome, Firefox, IE 11, or Safari, I am assuming it must be some sort of backwards compatability with older browsers?

I am assuming that these problematic browswers are checking the length of the value and getting a length of `undefined`, `null` or `NaN` which since it is not an integer is passing my validation? This is just a guess though.

Thoughts?

**EDIT: Oh I suppose the error could be on the server side to in receiving the fields and inserting them to the DB. Here's the PHP code which posts to SQL:**

```
$telephone = utf8_decode( mysql_real_escape_string($data->telephone) );

mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO contest 
        (prenom,
        nom,
        email,
        adresse,
        ville,
        code_postal,
        telephone,
        event_ticket,
        mailing_list,
        score,
        perfect_score,
        answer_1,
        answer_2,
        answer_3,
        answer_4,
        answer_5,
        answer_6,
        answer_7,
        answer_8,
        answer_9) 
    VALUES 
        ('$name', 
        '$familyName',
        '$email',
        '$address',
        '$city',
        '$postal',
        '$telephone',
        '$ticket',
        '$mailingList',
        '$score',
        '$perfectScore',
        '$answer1',
        '$answer2',
        '$answer3',
        '$answer4',
        '$answer5',
        '$answer6',
        '$answer7',
        '$answer8',
        '$answer9')"
);
```

Could the problem be with the escaped data?

Comment: Just a thought, it could be web scrapers or people messing with your system.  You can never trust content posted from the web and should probably be checking everything again on the post since people can use tools or write their own apps to post whatever they want without even visiting your page.

Comment: Hrmm I don't see how it could be scrapers. There are a lot of values in the form because the contest itself is a trivia game with many questions. There isn't a captcha but the bot scrapers would have to be pretty good to even complete the game and get to the final form

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that your visitors just have scripts disabled, which allows them to bypass your javascript?

Also, as others have mentioned, it's possible that you're getting visits from scrapers/bots/etc. You can try checking `navigator.userAgent` for more information about your visitors' browser/device.

Comment: Seeing as it's an angularjs project they'd not get far enough in the game with scripts disbaled to reach the user contact form